# The terms of use URL, /portal/terms_of_use is not working - I get a requested resource could not be found error

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I have configured my Liferay 7 site with a terms of use web content document.  It works perfectly when new users log in for the first time.

However, I need to be able to provide a link to review the terms of use.  The only thing I see is in the Liferay Portal struts-config.xml file, which is "/portal/terms_of_use".  But this link appended to my hostname is not working.  I get a "Not Found" error page ("The requested resource could not be found.").

Am I using the wrong URL?  I've tried searching for what the URL would be and have not found anything, which is surprising since I would think this is a common requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the routing of web-stuff to OSGi bundles, there's no longer any top-level URL that can be specified this way (there may never have been one). However, there is a way to get to it:

`http://localhost:8080/c/portal/terms_of_use` requires login, but results in the (in my case unconfigured) terms of use. The `/c` within the URL targets struts (and maybe something else - the `/portal` within targets a certain bundle (portal-web in this case)

Comment: Thank you Olaf. I tried /c/portal/terms_of_use and, as you said, it requires authentication.  That's not going to work, but your answer gave me the information I needed so I can forget this and move on to another approach.  On a separate note, I'm looking forward to "seeing" you at Devcon.